# SQL CLR execution error

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I am using visual studio 2012 and MS SQL Server 2012. I created SQL CLR project and followed the steps according to the following link
http://blogs.interfacett.com/how-create-net-stored-procedure-sql-server

Now when I insert data in  the table with which I attached a trigger, the data is inserted, but I get the following error.
"**Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.**"

Can anyone tell me, how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the permission set of the registered assembly to "Unrestricted" and check the result.

Comment: I am not allowed to change it. Its says "Alter Failed".

Comment: Why?! By which user you logged into the SQL? Also give me the error details please.

Comment: I am logged in with Windows default

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Alter failed for SqlAssembly 'SendNotification'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)


An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Comment: ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'NotificationSystem' failed because assembly 'NotificationSystem' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE.  The assembly is authorized when either of the following is true: the database owner (DBO) has UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission and the database has the TRUSTWORTHY database property on; or the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.

Comment: **Alter Database NotificationSystem Set Trustworthy On;** Execute this, then alter the assembly permission set. The reason of this is that you should tell the server to trust this database first, then you can have some unrestricted assemblies inside your database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not make web calls from triggers. Use a queue do decouple the transactional data operation from the non-transactional HTTP call. Do not make web calls from inside SQL CLR. Use an external process that makes the HTTP call.

Follow the permission requirements for code access as described in [CLR Integration Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx):

> **EXTERNAL_ACCESS** assemblies also have the following permissions and values:
>   ...
>   **WebPermission** Connect: Outbound connections to web resources are allowed.

Comment: oh God, I am making web calls from here.